# return The Id of selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, buttonclick

Hi there I have the following card that has 3 selectable buttons button.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0" role="tablist" id="FlightType" onclick="SelectedFlightType()">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <button class="nav-link active" id="oneway-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                            data-bs-target="#oneway" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="oneway"
                                            aria-selected="true">
                                            <span
                                                class="d-inline-block icon-20 rounded-circle bg-white align-middle me-2"></span>One-way
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <button class="nav-link" id="return-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                            data-bs-target="#return" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="return"
                                            aria-selected="false">
                                            <span
                                                class="d-inline-block icon-20 rounded-circle bg-white align-middle me-2"></span>Return
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <button class="nav-link" id="multiCity-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                                            data-bs-target="#multiCity" type="button" role="tab"
                                            aria-controls="multiCity" aria-selected="false">
                                            <span
                                                class="d-inline-block icon-20 rounded-circle bg-white align-middle me-2"></span>Multi-city
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
```

And I have this  button

```
<input id="btnSave" class="btn btn-search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="Search();" />
```

When I  click on the button I'm calling `Search()` function which will redirect to a different page accrording selected button in the `ul` element.

I want to return the Id of the selected button and use it in the  `Search()` function like this

```
var value = Search()

if(value == 'option1')
{
  //do something
}
else if(value == 'option2')
{
   //do another thing
}
else
{
   // do the rest thing
}
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
function valueFunction() {
            // var e = e || window.event;
            var e = window.event;
            e = e.target || e.srcElement;
            if (e.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
                var ft = e.id;
                
                alert(ft);

                return e.id;
            }
        }
```

this works fine when I call it in the onclick of the `ul` element which has the id of "FlightType"

```
function search(){
    var value = valueFunction();
   alert(values) //undefined for first option, not responding for the other 2 options
}
```

```js
var value = Search()

if (value == 'option1') {
  //do something
} else if (value == 'option2') {
  //do another thing
} else {
  // do the rest thing
}

function valueFunction() {
  // var e = e || window.event;
  var e = window.event;
  e = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (e.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    var ft = e.id;

    alert(ft);

    return e.id;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0" role="tablist" id="FlightType" onclick="SelectedFlightType()">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="oneway-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#oneway" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="oneway" aria-selected="true">
      <span class="d-inline-block icon-20 rounded-circle bg-white align-middle me-2"></span>One-way
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <button class="nav-link" id="return-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#return" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="return" aria-selected="false">
      <span class="d-inline-block icon-20 rounded-circle bg-white align-middle me-2"></span>Return
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <button class="nav-link" id="multiCity-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#multiCity" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="multiCity" aria-selected="false">
      <span class="d-inline-block icon-20 rounded-circle bg-white align-middle me-2"></span>Multi-city
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>

<input id="btnSave" class="btn btn-search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="Search();" />
```

plz direct me, I'm stuck for hrs.

Comment: Hi Najah, welcome to SO! What exactly is the problem? You say that it works with particular conditions, but working things don't sound like a problem to me. Can you give a set of circumstances where your code does not work and describe the abnormal behaviour? Please answer your post and add these elements :)

Comment: Najah, I've tried to convert your posted code into a live demo, in your question; could you please edit that snippet (click the 'edit' link, and then click on the 'edit the above snippet' link in the preview) to ensure it matches your code, so that we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the select html tag for this (with the option tags inside, each one has its own value)?

In an other way, your function valueFunction can't return you the id of buttons because you don't look for them if the DOM. The event is generated by the input you have clicked on

Comment: if you look closely, the buttons kinda working like Raddio button, a user selects of them, and clicks search

Answer (score 0):

```
by seeing your code  i understood  you have a few buttons implemented , all having id so you can just pass that id while onlick 

  



<input id="btnSave" class="btn btn-search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="Search('btnsave');" />
// in js code
function Search(id){
if(value == id)
{
  //do something
}
else if(value == id)
{
   //do another thing
}
else
{
   // do the rest thing
}
}
```

Comment: yup but where does the "id"  in value == id`  coems from?. the buttons are kinda like Radio buttons where the user selects one of them and clicks search